# SQL to get details based on other table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to get list of employees from table 'employee' based on their join_date which is in another table 'employee_details'.

For example: get list of employees names whose join_date is > 16-Feb-2020

[image]

Comment: simple inner join will give you the desired results..

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * 
from employee emp 
inner join employee_details dtls on emp.id=dtls.employee_id 
where join_date > '2020-02-16'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN Employee_Details D ON E.ID = D.Employee_ID
WHERE Join_Date > '16-Feb-2020'
```

Comment: There is no need to add comments such as "Hope this Query works for your case" as it doesn't add anything meaningful to the answer. Instead please add an actual explanation as to what you've done in order to help the OP learn.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.